# Expected argument type Selector [Swift]

Tags: swift, cocoa, selector, addtarget

I'm wanting to build a menu interface programically by setting up a `for` loop inside my main view controller which creates a bunch of buttons from a custom button class.

There are a few parameters I am passing to the button class, one of those is the action parameter for the `addTarget` function.

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(*****?*****), for: .touchUpInside)
```

I tried setting up an array of strings to pass to it but I get an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Selector'

I tried creating an array of type `Any` but the array values for the segue calls are confusing the compiler. So what kind of array can I make that can pass the type which is required by the #selector?

***Issue***

// Array declaration
var segueArray: [(Void)] = []

// Array initialisation

segueArray = [segueToDice1, segueToDice2, segueToDice3]

error Cannot assign value of type '[() -> ()]' to type '[(Void)]'

Comment: Please read the documentation for `UIControl`. The selector can only be one of three specific signatures.

Comment: Just a hint: SEL